# How to update res.locals after database operation & update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm trying to render a totalQty value in the navigation of my app but it currently doesn't update the res.locals after a database operation unless a user logs out and logs back in then it will update. So whenever a user adds a new item to cart, the totalQty basically just returns the old total items but I need it to update. Below are my lines of code for user model, index.js, shop routes and the navigation view.

Index.js:

```
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.session = req.session;
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
  res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
  res.locals.currentUser = req.session.user;
  next();
});
```

User Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'BASIC'
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  address: {
    type: String
  },
  apartment: {
    type: String
  },
  country: {
    type: String
  },
  state: {
    type: String
  },
  city: {
    type: String
  },
  zip: {
    type: String
  },
  phone: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  resetToken: String,
  resetTokenExpiration: Date,
  cart: {
    items: [
      {
        productId: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Product',
          required: true
        },
        quantity: { type: Number, required: true }
      },
    ],
    totalQty: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  }
}, { timestamps: true });

userSchema.methods.addToCart = function (product) {
  const cartProductIndex = this.cart.items.findIndex(cp => {
    return cp.productId.toString() === product._id.toString();
  });
  let newQuantity = 1;

  const updatedCartItems = [...this.cart.items];

  if (cartProductIndex >= 0) {
    newQuantity = this.cart.items[cartProductIndex].quantity + 1;
    updatedCartItems[cartProductIndex].quantity = newQuantity;

  } else {
    updatedCartItems.push({
      productId: product._id,
      quantity: newQuantity
    });
  }

  let initialValue = 0;
  totalQty = updatedCartItems.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
    return previousValue + currentValue.quantity
  }, initialValue);

  const updatedCart = {
    items: updatedCartItems,
    totalQty: totalQty
  };
  this.cart = updatedCart;
  return this.save();
};

userSchema.methods.removeFromCart = function (productId) {
  const updatedCartItems = this.cart.items.filter(item => {
    return item.productId.toString() !== productId.toString();
  });
  this.cart.items = updatedCartItems;
  return this.save();
};

userSchema.methods.clearCart = function () {
  this.cart = { items: [] };
  return this.save();
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Shop /cart routes GET & POST

```
exports.getCart = (req, res, next) => {
  // populate req user
  req.user
    .populate('cart.items.productId')
    .execPopulate()
    .then(user => {
      const products = user.cart.items;
      // render cart view
      res.render('shop/cart', {
        path: '/cart',
        pageTitle: 'Cart - Hashing365.com',
        products: products
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      const error = new Error(err);
      error.httpStatusCode = 500;
      return next(error);
    });
};

exports.postCart = (req, res, next) => {
  // extract prod ID
  const prodId = req.body.productId;
  // run DB find with prod ID
  Product.findById(prodId)
    .then(product => {
      // return true && add to cart
      return req.user.addToCart(product);
    })
    .then(result => {
      // re-render same page
      res.redirect('back');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      const error = new Error(err);
      error.httpStatusCode = 500;
      return next(error);
    });
};
```

Navigation view:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="/cart" class="nav-link">Cart <span id="totalQty"><%= session.user.cart.totalQty %></span></a>
</li>
```

So this code doesn't update on the res.locals.session unless user signs out and back in. Would appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: So, templates that are already rendered into the browser don't automatically update just because some value changed on the server.  Why are you expecting something to update?  What exact event causes something to update on the server and what exactly do you expect to cause the client to update?  I'm confused as to what you think should be working?  You will have to either have Javascript code in the client that updates the currently displayed web page in the browser or you will have to load some new page into the browser that can render with the new data.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've got a function on the cart model that gets and saves into an array the totalQuantity for cart items. When I perform the action to add to cart, this array is updated to include the new item quantity. Now, what I've been doing so far is get the sum of totalQuantity from the DB and making it available throughout the app using res.locals. This works first time I add an item to the cart, to get the new update after that, I'd have to logout and log back in. I don't want that, I want the value to be updated after the page re-loads.